# error: unknown command 'link' when linking @react-native-community/voice shows

Tags: react-native, react-native-community, react-native-voice

I'm trying to implement speech-to-text function in ReactNative. The steps I've done:

1.Run `npm i @react-native-community/voice --save` in VSCode terminal

2.`react-native link @react-native-community/voice`. Then it shows .ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system but I solved it. But another problem occurred, it shows `error: unknown command 'link'`. I then found that `link and unlink commands have been removed from react-native cli.` Hence, I have to rely on autolinking, but how do I autolink them or do i have to do it manually? Or is there any other tool that can be used for speech-to-text?

**Version:**

```
"react-native": "0.70.0",
"@react-native-community/voice": "^1.1.9",
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah..  You don't need to manually 'link' libraries as it has been dropped in the newer version of React-Native.